# keyboard layout changed => problem with BIOS password. Can't boot

Tags: boot, password, keyboard-layout, bios

my keyboard layout seems to randomly have changed. If I didn't have a power-on/BIOS password set up on that machine, it wouldn't be a problem, I could easily find out what layout is being used from the log in screen and switch back to my preferred layout, or use the virtual keyboard.

Not so lucky: I can't boot, get to a terminal window and I'm running out of standard keyboard layout examples.

Device: Lenovo Ideacentre K430

OS: Ubuntu 16.4 (desktop version, not server)

I tried:

- different wireless and wired mechanical keyboards. Some special characters I need are not recognised (i.e. I hit a special character key and it does not  register. All standard characters and numerical pad input seem to register OK though).
- typing in the password looking at different keyboard layouts online, but many special characters require to use SHIFT in other layouts, which is not a key you can use for BIOS passwords.
- clearing the password through resetting the jumper*s* (Edit: no result, regardless of how long I switch from standard position Pin 1&2 to Clear CMOS position Pin 2&3, which I tried for each jumper individually and then for both. Why the motherboard has 2 Clear CMOS jumpers is a mystery to me)
- removing the CMOS battery (makes no difference, even when removed for over 15 min and whilst the jumpers are on Clear CMOS position)

If anyone has had the same issue and fixed it, I'd really appreciate if they could share their knowledge. I don't have a spare tower to install my hard drive in :(

Thanks in advance
LCz

Comment: Hi, have exactly the same problem. Could you fix it? Surprisingly, the problem occurred after registering a new user with sudo passwd

Comment: Hi Tangui

Left the CMOS battery out for 10 days and it still didn't clear the BIOS password :(

The solution in my case was (too) simple, I'm embarrassed to say, but it won't help you much.
Had not used that particular desktop for >6 months and *finally* realised my mistake, namely that I had been trying to use the OS log in password instead of the BIOS password. Duh!

Not the answer you were looking for, I know...
Good luck unlocking your machine

Comment: Exactly the same... :) Except it was day to day. Simply was tired because of work!